# PHP5 JSON missing, but installed

Tags: php, json

I've installed Apache2 and PHP5 with some modes. Also, I've installed PHP5-JSON and PHP5-MCRYPT. But I can't see this modules in **php -m** .

When I run **php5enmode json** I can see warning:

> Module json ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php5/mods-available

If I run apt-get install php5-json, I will have information, that php5-json was installed in the newest version.

**dpkg --get-selections | grep php5** shows:

```
libapache2-mod-php5         install    
php5                        install    
php5-cgi                    install    
php5-cli                    install    
php5-common                 install    
php5-curl                   install    
php5-fpm                    deinstall    
php5-gd                     install
php5-imagick                install    
php5-imap                   install    
php5-intl                   install    
php5-json                   install
php5-mcrypt                 install    
php5-memcache               install    
php5-memcached              install    
php5-ming                   install    
php5-mongo                  deinstall    
php5-mysql                  install    
php5-pgsql                  deinstall    
php5-ps                     install    
php5-pspell                 install    
php5-readline               install    
php5-recode                 install    
php5-snmp                   install    
php5-sqlite                 install    
php5-tidy                   install    
php5-xcache                 deinstall    
php5-xdebug                 deinstall    
php5-xmlrpc                 install    
php5-xsl                    install
```

In `/usr/lib/php5/20121212` I have:

> curl.so, gd.so, imagick.so, imap.so, intl.so, json.so, mcrypt.so, memcached.so, memcache.so, ming.so, mysqli.so, mysql.so, opcache.so, pdo_mysql.so, pdo.so, pdo_sqlite.so, pspell.so, ps.so, readline.so, recode.so, snmp.so, sqlite3.so, tidy.so, xmlrpc.so, xsl.so

JSON and MCRYPT is exist, but how to include to PHP ?

In `/var/lib/php5/modules/registry` I have json and mcrypt.

Comment: Well, does an .ini file for the json module exist in `/etc/php5/mods-available`? Maybe someone accidentally deleted it?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo service php5 restart`?

Comment: `/etc/php5/mods-available` is empty.
`php5: unrecognized service` after restart

Comment: I deleted all stuff of apache2 and php5, include config files, and now it works. Maybe old config made a problem.